# textfield onChanged() {setstate} doesn't work in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, setstate

I wanna change color of button when user type at least one character on textfield
also wanna change color when textfield is empty

so I tryed to flag(boolean) to make it

```
onChanged: (value) {
    if (value.length == 0) {
      setState(() {
        _isTimeFilled = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isTimeFilled = true;
      });
    }
},

...

_isFilled ? Colors.grey : Colors.green
```

but it only change color when textfield unfocused

i tryed provider too but it's same.
how can i fix this?

here's my code

```
    void _changeButtonColor(int value) {✅✅✅✅
    if (value == 0) {
      setState(() => _isTimeFilled = false);
    } else {
      setState(() => _isTimeFilled = true);
    }
  }
  
    TextFormField TimeTextFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      focusNode: timeFocusNode,
      autofocus: true,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      onChanged: (value) {
        _changeButtonColor(value.length);✅✅✅✅
      },
      
      
      RaisedButton(
            focusColor: Colors.white,
            splashColor: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            color: _isTimeFilled ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.grey, ✅✅✅✅
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity, child: Icon(Icons.check)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Check your variable _isTimeFilled must be above @override build.

Comment: right below class name 

Answer (score 6):

Do this:

```
onChanged: (value) {
    _isTimeFilled = (value != 0);
    setState(() { });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The onChanged of a TextField is a string as an argument.
And, _isFilled and _isTimeFilled need to be unified.

So,

```
onChanged: (value) {
  if (value.length <= 0) {
    setState(() {
      _isFilled = false;
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _isFilled = true;
    });
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution but don't know exactly the cause. Just managed to make it.

solution: make a stateful widget and call it.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context, scrollController) => inputForms(),
          );
        },
```

`inputForms` is method which return form fields.

solution: make form fields stateful widget and import it

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
        showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context, scrollController) => StatefulFormFields(),
    );
},
```